# Keeping a key pressed

Tags: java, keyboard, key, mouse

In my application I would like to add an key event where a couple of keys are constantly pressed.

If I go off my application, they're still pressed. Its kind of hard to explain but I would like my computer to think I am pressing these keys or mouse down.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Any pieces of could we could help you improve?

Comment: Just basic code of making an application to put the code within. The Jframes and such. I want to put the code within a button which when I click it it enables the code.

Comment: You're going to have to simulate a event (ActionEvent, KeyEvent or MouseEvent) by creating the event from scratch and passing it to the appropriate listener object.  Without more information (i.e. a better explanation) from you, a more concrete solution would be speculative at best.